Is my income haram if the way I earn is halal but illegal?
I live in a non muslim country,and recently I started working for a 'tree planting' company. So they import the quarter of their trees from foreign countries but gets the rest illegally from mountains, but the tree is not considered rare or about to be extinct, it's just illegal to take trees from mountains. Islamicly it is a good deed to plant a tree and it's also halal to get trees from mountains but since it is illegal in my country,is my income haram or am I just sinfull for doing illegal stuff?

Welcome to Islam StackExchange. Unfortunately, your question is highly specific and warrants a fatwa for you, and for that, I recommend you visit seekersguidance.org, islamqa.info, askimam.org, or some other fatwa Q&A site. As a general response to this, I believe it depends on how exactly you retrieve the illegal trees. The mountains should likely be government property and not public property, so it gives them the ownership of it and things that are grown on it, and if that's the case, this should tantamount to stealing and would make your income facilitating it haram. But Idk the specifics-

in your case and the property and type of government, so cannot comment. But generally, if said illegal or legal object is owned by someone and you take it without their consent, it is stealing.
